# Book on Modern System Architecture for Web applications

Tags: lamp, scaling

I'm looking for some reading material on architecting and system admin tools etc for building web applications from small to large detailing the recommended and appropriate steps as you grow?

In my case the environment is a LAMP.

Comment: You are basically asking for a [shopping recommendation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/), which we don't do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are three books to get you started:

[Web Operations: Keeping the Data On Time](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1449377440)

[Scalable Internet Architectures](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/067232699X)

[Building Scalable Web Sites: Building, Scaling, and Optimizing the Next Generation of Web Applications](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0596102356)

Cheers